# Spring Security with X-Auth-Token for REST API's

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

we have an application in Spring boot using Spring Security for authorization and authentication of REST API's.

We have a REDIS server running, which along with spring security stores X-AUTH-TOKEN and sends it as a HEADER parameter for 404 RESPONSE to user who executes a /login attempt.

This X-AUTH-TOKEN can then be used as a header parameter to authenticate other REST API's.

The problem here is that user can copy this X-AUTH-TOKEN and use it from another machine and bypass the login credentials on which X-AUTH-TOKEN is generated.

How to disable this security breach in Spring Security token based?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSON web tokens then you can add a custom field in the claims that can uniquely identify the machine and validate if its same.

The post [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64541/can-i-prevent-a-replay-attack-of-my-signed-jwts) can be useful too if you don't mind making your application stateful.